# XML validation against a schema defined in multiple and interdependent xsd files

Tags: xml, xsd

I am very new to XML and understand the basics. Here is my situation, I have a sample XML file that I wish to validate against a schema defined in an XSD file. Easy enough, there are many cut and paste utilities for this online I see that. However, I see no way to use these utilities when faced with an XSD file which references other XSD files or put another way when dealing with validation using multiple XSD files. I am not trying to do this in code (programmatically) its just an outside double check I wish to perform. I just need to know if it can be done and be pointed to a utility I can use.

Comment: Any utility that will validate XML against a schema must be using a validating XML parser, which means that it must work as long as (1) the schema is correctly using an `import` or `include` statement; and (2) the utility is able to access all of the files that make up the schema.

Comment: @David Makes very good sense. Thanks. Do you know if XMLSpy does this?

Comment: As I said, it must, otherwise it's not a valid XML parser.  It's not optional, it's part of the specification.